# deploy a war file html5, angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, war, webstorm

I'm developing a pure html& JavaScript (AngularJS) web application, and I need to deploy a war file?
Is there any way to do it using the webStorm? if not is there any manual way to do that?

Regards,
Ramzy

Answer (score 0):

You just put the builded war file into the `/webapps` folder of your servlet container (I assume it is a tomcat server) and voila!

Comment: WebStorm provides no support for packaging applications for deployment/deploying to application servers. So you have to do this manually as suggested by @Mr_Mig

Comment: Yes, I know, the question how to make a war file from pure html?

Comment: @RamzyAbourafeh You should rephrase your question in the main content then.
You need a special folder structure with `/WEB-INF` dir and `web.xml` descriptor file in it. 
Then you can simply zip the folder with project and change it's extension to `war`.
See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format)